# How to get geometry type of wms layer in openlayer?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

```
     var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("WMSLayer",
                "localhost:8080/geoserver/workspacewms",
                {
                   srs: 'EPSG:4326',
                   layers: "workspace:name1",format:'image/png',
                   transparent: true
                },
                { 
                   isBaseLayer: false,
                } 
);
    map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The base WMS protocol does not have a way to give you that information.

Since the example you are looking at seems GeoServer specific, you can run a WFS DescribeFeatureType on the same layer to get that information though.

A bit more standard way is to run a WMS/SLD DescribeLayer request first (assuming the server supports it, it's optional, GeoServer does support it though) which in turn will give you a link to the WFS DescribeFeatureType, so, in the end, you end up just doing one more step (but you're following the OGC specs to the letter when doing so).